# Keynote video pausing/playing

Tags: video, presentation

I have an idea for linking a keynote presentation with a video (exported from a 3d tool).  The idea is that each time you 'click' (as you would to move to the next slide/transition) it would play x more frames of the video then pause.  So frame 1-30 might be the first animation, and it would pause on frame 30.  Then, you click again and it plays 31-60, stopping on 60.

Is such a thing possible and if so how would I achieve it?  Assume a video file is available in the required format.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of would be to actually do it as multiple videos and stills.  Have the first video play and then go to a still of the last frame.  The next would be the next video clip followed by the still.  Continue doing that for the length of it.  Not sure if it works like that in Keynote or not, but that's how I'd do it in any of my sequencing/presentation packages.

Comment: Many thanks, you're right.  You mentioned other sequencing/pres packages - are there any potentially more suitable ones I should check out?

Comment: @Glinkot - unfortunately all my stuff is PC based rather than Mac and tends to run the higher end.

Comment: I run both, so any mentions still appreciated :)

Comment: ProPresenter is one of the ones I typically use for doing sequencing.  It's built more specifically as a media sequencer and so it gives better overall control of the order of things, but less "fluff" in the way of animation of text and such.